# randomly select multichoice options

Tags: python, numpy

I want to select multiple items from a set of options. Each option has its own set of probabilities for getting selected or not selected.

Fox example:
*Choices, "yes", "no"*
"September", 0.90, 0.10
"October", 0.25, 0.75
"November", 0.45, 0.55
"December", 0.50, 0.50

"yes" means the option getting selected and "no" means not selected. So for the first roll, the selections may be ["September", "December"], for the second roll it can be ["September", "October", "November"] and so on.

It is similar to checkbox choices where choosing or not choosing one option is independent of other choices.

I can do it through numpy.random.choice by looping into every given choice. But I want to know if there is a more elegant/efficient way to do it?

This is what I did

```
choices = {
    "September":0.90,
    "October":0.25,
    "November":0.45,
    "December":0.50
}

resp = []
for ch, pr in choices:
    pick = 1
    probs = [pr, 1-pr]
    select = ["yes", "no"]
    choose = numpy.random.choice(select, pick, probs)
    if "yes" in choose[0]:
        resp.append(ch)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `numpy.random.uniform` function to generate samples in the interval `[0,1]`. By comparing these to the probabilities in `choices`, you can create random samples with the specified probabilities. Thanks to the automatic broadcasting, each column is compared to the corresponding probability from `choices`.

That way you can create a matrix with the dimensions `(n_rolls, n_choices)`, where `n_rolls` is the number of times you want to repeat this (this could be `1` if you just need one sample), and `n_choices` is the number of different choices.

```
import numpy
from collections import OrderedDict

choices = OrderedDict()
choices["September"] = 0.90
choices["October"] = 0.25
choices["November"] = 0.45
choices["December"] = 0.50

n_rolls = 5
probs = numpy.random.uniform(size=(n_rolls, len(choices)))
samples = probs < choices.values()
```

The result will be a bool array, where every column corresponds to an option from `choices` and each row contains one try. As we used an `OrderedDict`, the result will be ordered in the same way as you entered the dictionary data.

```
>>> samples
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

As a test: let's find the probability of each column for `n_rolls=1000000`:

```
>>> numpy.mean(samples, axis=0)
array([ 0.899713,  0.249405,  0.449437,  0.499881])
```

To convert this result to a list like the one you specified, you can use a combination of `numpy.where` and `numpy.choose`:

```
res = numpy.choose(numpy.where(samples[0, :]), choices.keys())

print samples[0,:],'\n',res
[ True False  True  True] 
[['September' 'November' 'December']]
```

Unfortunately, this part only works for one single row, so if you have multiple rolls, you'll need to do this final step in a loop.

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted. Thx.